# Storage and data exchange

Tags: android, database

I get a variable from an external source. I have to compare it with the previous variable, and if they are different to rewrite a new place of the old.
I thought doing it in string.xml, but they can not change the data programmatically. How can I make the necessary functionality? Only the database?

Comment: Are you referring to persisting data from one instance of the app to another? (This data coming form an external source)

Comment: No, from JSON parser I get a variable, and it is necessary to compare it with something, and if the new variables more than the old, the new rewrite instead of the old. I decided to do it with a file. This is a good decision?

Comment: Well if it's a single variable that will change, you should use SharedPreferences. If you're using this a lot with a lot of data you should use a SqlLite database. If it's just a small amount of data, though, and read time isn't as critical, a file should be fine

Comment: Thank you! I select SharedPreferences